# Using PHP value in CSS text background across multiple pages

Tags: php, html, css

I have a text style that uses an image on a page to create an outline of that image over text. For example, here is how it appears when the text is set to 'CONTACT US'.

[image]

**CSS**

```
<style>
    .heading-background {
        background: url(<?php the_field('background'); ?>) center center / cover;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }
</style>
```

I am using WordPress and the background is selected through PHP, which requires me to place a style block on each page that it is used. If I need to make changes, I have to find each style block and update them all individually. I can't move it to a CSS file as the PHP variable is necessary for the background to display.

Is it possible to move this class into a single file to send a PHP variable to and receive the updated block back?

Comment: put all this style in a php file where you echo out this tag and then include this php on every page. This way if you ever have to change anything, just change the included php file.

Comment: You can extract this chunk to a separate php file and include it with include_once or require_once into all pages. Alternatively you can generate css file with php but I think it will be an overkill for this case.

Comment: Agree with comments.  Someday maybe [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables#Browser_compatibility) would be an option.

Comment: CSS variables are an options, although support is not great for IE etc, but they're relatively okay if that's not a problem.

Comment: No IE and weak mobile support.  http://caniuse.com/css-variables/embed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If I understand this correctly*, you could put the CSS inside a file called something like `background.php`. Then include that on each page but above it get the background and put it in a php variable. So something like this:

***background.php***

```
<style>
    .heading-background {
        background: url(<?php echo $bg_field; ?>) center center / cover;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }
</style>
```

***page_1.php***

```
<?php $bg_field = get_field('background'); ?>
<?php get_template_part('background'); ?>
```

And then repeat for however many page templates you have. Here is some bonus information about the [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) function.

Comment: This was very helpful for solving it! I had trouble with `get_template_part` passing the variable, `include(locate_template('background.php'));` worked for me instead.